# Does it sound natural to say: "I failed as a failure"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, idiomatic-language

Can a person who is a failure and who failed to get this point across, which means he couldn't prove others that he is a failure, say:

> "I failed as a failure"?

Comment: IMO no: it would make you an even bigger failure. It's a paradox: if you managed to get across the idea that you are a failure, that would be a success.

Comment: Is this a "real" situation that you find yourself in?  If not what is the reason or context of the question?

Comment: Lol. yes, it happened to me.. I tried to convince my teammates that I'm a failure and cannot lead the school project. Later, when I said it to my sister, I thought of the option of saying: I failed as a failure.

Comment: Eh, I can think of contexts where the sentence "I failed as a failure" can make sense: Say you are betting against yourself in some competition, and you know since you are a Failure$^{TM}$, you are destined to fail. However, you then fail in your task to fail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's redundant by itself, and doesn't make much sense. You're just saying he's a failure.

You need to add something in your situation. Something like:

> I failed **to convince you** I'm a failure.

It's the "get this point across" part that's missing in your example.